# Xamarin Android Player Virtual Box Error VT-x is not available

Tags: android, xamarin, windows-8.1, virtualbox, xamarin-android-player

I have Windows 8.i 64 bits and I installed Xamarin Studio 5.9.6 and Xamarin Android Player V.0.6.2. It installed Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.4.

I installed Nexus 4 (KitKat) Device.

My problem is that VM Virtual Box do not start... I have the error

> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

In Oracle VM Administration Configuration it appear Windows 8.1 32 bits... (64 bits is not available)

I check the PC BIOS and "Virtualization" is Enabled

Is there a way to make it work?

thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have a 32-bit version of Windows 8.1.

Comment: Do you have a CPU that supports VT-x? http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Hyper-V enabled?  If so disable it and reboot, if it is disabled then use the guides here (assuming Intel) to ensure VT-X is supported - http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-030729.htm